# ffmpeg: recommend baseline options on bad results

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4

I am running windows services to convert about 10k videos per year.
Most of videos make no problem, but there are some videos where I didnt see the problem:

[Source Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnznqwzgx402rdu/_in2.mp4?dl=0)

[Video after conversion](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02ichwd2qn7p7sm/out.mp4?dl=0)

=> The value of -b:v is extracted from FFProbe to get better results if the machine supports GPU encoding

Most videos are running on this samle cmd:

```
-i in.mp4 -an -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 55600 -vf yadif -g 25 -movflags +faststart -y out.mp4
```

As far as I understand the problem: FFProbe returns only the avg bitrate wich is way to low.
I have tried to switch to -b:v, -maxrate:v, -bufsize:v with medium results. The videos are mutch better but still below the org file. even with the same bitrates like the org file.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to convert all videos to baseline?
2. Is it still recommend to convert videos to baseline if its mandotory to support the majorety of devices (PC/Mac/Android/IPhone)?
3. Any idea how to detect videos my conversion has ruined without human interaction?

Unfortunately the videos are confidential, but i have cut a sample and here are the org meta data. The bad result is below:

```
Video 
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L4
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames     : 5 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 19 min 2 s
Bit rate                       : 801 kb/s
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 30.000 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.013
Stream size                    : 109 MiB (76%)
Writing library                : x264 core 160 r10 33f9e14
Encoding settings              : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=34 / lookahead_threads=5 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / stitchable=1 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=infinite / keyint_min=30 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=5 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=5500 / vbv_bufsize=15000 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                   : UTC 2020-05-07 15:14:22
Tagged date                    : UTC 2020-05-07 15:14:22
Color range                    : Limited
Color primaries                : BT.709
Transfer characteristics       : BT.709
Matrix coefficients            : BT.709
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the issue?  Why are you trying to match the bitrate at all? Why not use crf encoding?

> Is it still recommend to convert videos to baseline if its mandotory to support the majorety of devices (PC/Mac/Android/IPhone)?

The last iPhone that could not play high profile was released over 8 years ago. Unless you need support for an iPhone 4, No.

> Any idea how to detect misguided videos without human interaction?

What is a "misguided" video?

Comment: > Way exactly is the issue? 
I have edided the question and put the resulting video to the top, if you take a look you will very poor quality.

This services are running since 10 years and were made by students. I was put in charge to updated them to use hardware encoding. 
I am just basic user of FFMPEG. I need some time to answer the qestion why we not use crf.
The videos are used mostly for streaming but also for PC/Mac High quality presentations.

> What is a "misguided" video?
a bad translation, what i ment was: total crap

Answer (score 0):

Thx szatmary for pushing me into the right direction!

1. Is there a better way to convert all videos to baseline?

   A: Yes, dont use baseline
2. Is it still recommend to convert videos to baseline if its mandotory to support the majorety of devices (PC/Mac/Android/IPhone)?

   A: No! We will switch to the High Profile, and try crf for streaming (a lot of static content)
3. Any idea how to detect videos my conversion has ruined without human interaction?

   A: search for 'crf' at the org. Encoding settings. Converting them to constant bitrate need other strategies